# In Ruby on Rails, if you have the association wrong in the models, will it affect your app if you only touch model.instance_variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, associations

That is, if you have all the `has_many`, `has_one`, `belongs_to`, and `has many ... :through` and `has_many_and_belongs_to` wrong, but your program only touch the

```
model.instance_variable
```

but not

```
model.some_other_model    # or model.some_other_model.some_method_or_variable
```

will you app do anything wrong or do anything bad to the database?  That is, if your association is defined wrong, will it not do anything wrong if you keep to that model but not "cross reference" another model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the *syntax* is correct, an error about a bad association won't be thrown until you try to access that association.

Comment: i think if you happen to have that key in either of your table, then you may not even see an error, such as matching the wrong primary key or foreign key by the wrong field.